# Free memory with explicit size

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I'm looking for `malloc`/`free`-like APIs in mainstream OSs that allow me to specify an explicit size during both allocation and de-allocation. What I hope to gain by this is that the runtime might spend less memory on bookkeeping when the allocated size is already available in the program.

On e.g. windows I only found `free()`, `_aligned_free()`, and `_freea()`, none of which take a second argument for size.

Comment: *"What I hope to gain by this, is that the runtime might spend less memory on bookkeeping"* And instead your program would spend the memory keeping track of the size?

Comment: Exactly, often that information is already needed/available.

Comment: @Blaze This is actually a valid question because programs typically track sizes of object regardless.

Comment: As for question itself, there is no such APIs, you'll need to write a custom allocator.

Comment: `mmap()`/`munmap()` maybe?

Comment: I think that you need to widen the search. There are a lot of custom, 3rd party allocators (not just OS API), which can be used. And even, if there is no such allocator, maybe you can modify one. I know, this would be a "library search" question, which is not allowed here.

Comment: @Blaze: in an average C++ program, the allocation size almost always known. `std::vector`? Known. Any polymorphic object? Known. Any object array with non-trivial destructor? Known. It's a shame, that we store size information duplicated most of the time (and/or we don't provide this information to the allocator, so it can be faster).

Comment: Wait, _who_ knows the allocated size of a polymorphic object? It's not stored in the object, so if you `delete` via base-class pointer, where is it tracked other than by the allocator?

Comment: Well, if it's polymorphic, it should have a virtual destructor, and the actual class will know its sizeof. @Useless

Comment: Sure, but that means the most-derived destructor has to handle deallocation _after_ its object has been fully destroyed. It's a bit hairy, and not at all the way delete expressions work now.

Comment: Also, C++14 actually defines an overload of operator delete which takes a pointer and a size, and it looks like jemalloc actually doesn't ignore the size.
Still, it'll probably create more problems than it tries to solve, so I don't see an actual benefit of trying to use that.

Comment: *What I hope to gain by this, is that the runtime might spend less memory on bookkeeping, when the allocated size is already available in the program.*  One major problem: you'd be adding a path for creating really nasty bugs. Right now, heap management is done by dedicated, extremely well-tested OS-supplied library code. That code doesn't need to be retested every time you change your application code. Once you move heap management into your application, you will **NOT** test it as well as the OS-supplied heap management code gets tested, but will have to retest it for all app code changes.

Comment: @Useless: actually, this is a common thing to do for compilers to merge the destructor call with delete: https://godbolt.org/z/JC_bT- . But even, if they didn't do it, it is not hard to put sizeof into the vtable.

Comment: It's known _somewhere_ yes. But not at the site of the delete expression as currently specified.

Comment: @geza -- re: "the allocation size is almost always known" -- no. The **requested** size is almost always known. The memory manager can (and does) allocate **more** memory than was requested. And it's not always the same amount for the same requested size.

Comment: @AndrewHenle -- minor technical point: memory management is usually done in the standard library; the granularity of OS-supplied memory blocks is generally too large for efficient memory allocation. The standard library code calls the OS to get large blocks, which it subdivides as needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker: And why does this matter?

Comment: @geza -- because the memory manager still has to store the actual size of the block.

Comment: @PeteBecker: If the chunk is much bigger, than it makes sense to split it (so it would has exact size). If it is just slightly larger, this information can be stored into the header of the block. Furthermore, where OP's case is mostly interesting (small block size), it doesn't matter, because block size will be always exact. Currently, memory allocators need to do some tricks to determine the area of the block (small/large). If they provided the size, these tricks are unneeded.

Comment: @Useless: why does it needed at the site of delete expression? It should be needed when `free()` is called.

Comment: @geza -- re:"this information can be stored into the header of the block". Yes, that's what I said: the memory manager still has to store the actual size of the block. Your suggestions for how this can be avoided would mean that memory managers would be severely constrained in order to meet those requirements, and it's not at all clear that such a constrained memory manager would be optimal.

Comment: @PeteBecker: it is different, that the allocator needs to store 1-2 bits (this is the case for the slightly larger case), or it needs to store a full 4/8-byte size field. And again, this is not the only issue. Allocators needs to identify the block, whether it is small/large. Why would this memory manager constrained in any way? It could work exactly as other allocators, it could ignore the size information at `free`. But, it could use it for benefit. I've designed several memory allocators in the past, and size information at `free` definitely helps in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking for malloc/free-like APIs in mainstream OSs that allow me to specify an explicit size during both allocation and de-allocation.

I'm not aware of any.

> What I hope to gain by this, is that the runtime might spend less memory on bookkeeping, when the allocated size is already available in the program.

This idea certainly can work, but there are a couple of drawbacks:

1. you have to partition allocation regions between objects whose allocated size is tracked by the caller, and objects where the allocator still needs to record that itself.

   This increases complexity and potentially memory fragmentation.
2. you have to allocate *exactly* the size the program requests.

   That is, a normal allocator could decide to return a 96-byte chunk for a 64-byte request, because it's just been freed, is hot on cache, and splitting and re-coalescing chunks smaller than 64 bytes is not deemed worthwhile.

   Your allocator can't do that, in general (it is limited to rounding up to the next aligned chunk size).

---

Of course, there are plenty of specialized allocators that manage these tradeoffs explicitly.

Using or writing these is a perfectly normal thing to do when the general-purpose allocator isn't a good fit for your allocation patterns. But, they're generally not provided by the language or OS, because they're *not* general-purpose. They're provided by libraries (or by yourself).

Examples:

1. You allocate and free a lot of objects with a previously-known fixed size.

   Write an object pool allocator for them. It doesn't need to track the allocation size, because it's always the same (often a template parameter). You don't need to explicitly track it in your code either, because it's implied by the type.
2. Variable-sized allocations of trivial objects all with the same lifetime (eg, lots of char buffers).

   Write an arena allocator. It doesn't need to track *individual* allocation sizes, because you reset the entire allocator instead of freeing and re-allocating individual objects. You never explicitly delete the allocate objects, because they're trivial anyway.

NB. If you choose to integrate your allocator using `new`/`delete` overloads (and think it will benefit from the explicit size parameter) you absolutely can use the ones Maxim points out, with the following caveat:

> ... [explicit size overloads will be] Called instead of [the default overloads] if a user-defined replacement is provided, except that it's unspecified [which] is called when deleting objects of incomplete type and arrays of non-class and trivially-destructible class types.

Answer (score 0):

`operator delete` family does accept the size. See [`operator delete`, `operator delete[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete):

> ```
> void operator delete  (void* ptr, std::size_t sz) noexcept;
> void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t sz) noexcept;
> void operator delete  (void* ptr, std::size_t sz, std::align_val_t al) noexcept;
> void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t sz, std::align_val_t al) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Called instead of `void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept` and `void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept;` if a user-defined replacement is provided.

With the benefit of the compiler providing the size for you.

Comment: The reference you are quoting also says "A memory allocator can use the given size to be more efficient. The standard library implementations are identical to (1-2)". So it still is necessary to write a custom allocator?

Comment: @B_old You would need to replace the global `new` and these versions of `delete` to use your custom allocator that accepts the size on deallocation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for faster malloc & free, there is a new (13 Feb 2019) drop-in replacement for systems that already support a hardware memory manager unit, MMU. Most computers do, most micro-controllers don't.

There is a paper and a study that shows it reduces Firefox's memory by 16% and Redis by 39%.

It is called Mesh.  [Mesh dynamic memory allocation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04738)